# Why would I use a polymorphic relations when I can make a simple has_many/belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reviewing associations and ran into this article about polymorphic associations [Polymorphic associations](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2/). In the article, it has the following code:

```
# Without polymorphism

class Post
  belongs_to :person
  belongs to :group
end


class Person
   has_many :posts
end


class Group
  has_many :posts
end
```

The article says the following about the above code

> Normally, to find out who owns a certain profile, we look at the column that is the foreign_key. A foreign_key is an id used to find the related object in the related model’s table.
>
> However, our Posts table would have two competing foreign keys:
>   group_id and person_id. This would be problematic.
>
> When trying to find the owner of a post, we would have to make a point
>   to check both columns to find the correct foreign_key, rather than
>   relying on one. What happens if we run into a situation where both
>   columns have a value?

I don't see the problem here. Why couldn't I use this for example `@post = Post.where(group_id: 1) or Post.where(person_id: 1)`

Why would changing the association to polymorphism make the code better? For example, `has_many: :through` creates a table with two foreign keys as shown in the rails guides. Yes, the three models in that example are connected to each other while the code above only has two models connected together. I'm not seeing why I would opt for the polymorphic option though.

Considering that polymorphic associations generate no foreign keys and are susceptible to incorrect data. Why would it be better? Thanks.

Comment: The polymorphism avoids the possibility that a post might appear to be both from a user and from group, which would not be an allowed state in the app, but the database would permit. Both ids not nil is a condition you'd have to manage in your code and do something about if it happened to be true.

Comment: For the given scenario it is feasible to handle it the way you are expressing and I have done so in the past when I can be sure that an object will be limited to, generally, 2 mutually exclusive associated objects. If you cannot guarantee this or already know the number of mutually exclusive associated objects will be greater than 2 then I would recommend polymorphism because managing the relationship details via an xor association becomes very tedious and tenuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism allows you to reuse code which in turn makes your application code scalable. For example, if I had 10 models that all needed an address record I could create a polymorphic association which would only require that I create two extra columns. The first column would be the `adressable_type` and the second would be the `addressable_id`. At any point I could grab an address and find its parent with the EXACT SAME CODE or create an address from any of the parents with the EXACT SAME CODE. So I'm sure you are saying well can't I do this anyway? Yes you can but if you don't use polymorphism then you must create a foreign key for each parent. So each time you want to associate a parent model with a child address you must create another migration with another foreign key which prevents you from being able to reuse your code.

So grabbing the parent of the first `Address` would look like this within a polymorphic association.

```
parent = Address.first.addressable
```

Without polymorphism it would look something like this:

```
def parent_record
    if self.customer_id.present?
        return self.customer
    elsif self.some_other_parent_id.present?
        return self.some_other_parent
    end
end

parent = Address.first.parent_record
```

Also, you'd have to add the following line of code for each association. Otherwise you won't be able to create a record.

```
 belongs_to :customer, optional: true
 belongs_to :some_other_parent, optional: true
```

Now let's say you actually want to run a validation to make sure you don't accidentally add multiple associations to the same record (that would break your entire process if you did and your data would be invalid aka 'worthless'). That's going to be pretty difficult. With polymorphism, you don't have to worry about that because there is only one foreign key.

If you don't implement polymorphic associations and later attempt to use single table inheritance, this would make your code logic very difficult to follow.

These are just a couple of small reasons why you should use polymorphic associations. Besides, it's good coding practice and makes logical sense to use when you have the possibility for different types of parent models for a given model. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Really helped alot.